# Android Gallery (view) video (also thumbnail issues)

Tags: android, image, video, thumbnails, gallery

Currently we have a Gallery view to which we need to add thumbnails for images/video. How do we get the already generated thumbnails (the ones that the native Gallery app shows) if we already have the image's/video's content:// URI?

(We are using Android 1.6, Video.Thumbnails does not exist)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.. working very nicely....!
http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have images and videos served by content provider and accessible as URIs. You want to create thumbnails for such images and videos.

I don't know how to do this with video files, but this is how I will implement it with image files.

1. Open the image as InputStream using ContentResolver's openInputStream method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29
2. Create a BitmapDrawable with the above InputStream using this method
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20java.io.InputStream%29
3. Scale down the BitmapDrawable to desired width and height of thumbnail. Follow this tutorial.
   http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html
4. [Optional] You may want to cache the thumbnail, so that you don't have to repeat above steps everytime the user accesses your Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I think for Images, the answers above could be useful. For videos, the class MediaMetadataRetriever is what is used by the native Gallery app., but unfortunately, that is not a published API.