# Insert video to android gallary

Tags: android, file, save, gallery, mediastore

i need to Know how to insert video to android gallery or make my own folder in gallery to shows my app photos and videos 
for example if i have my photo pathe like this

```
     File file = new File(storagePath, FileName);
     String MyPath= ""+Uri.fromFile(file);
```

what is the next step ?

Comment: try going here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114168/android-mediastore-insertvideo

Comment: you can accept the answer I provided for further people like yourself looking for help below. :)