# Adding video to Android Content Manager

Tags: android, video

As you can see, I'm new here (but not new to programming).  I'm working on my first android camera app, and I cant get my video files to show up in the gallery.  I understand that I need to inform the system of my new file's Content Values, but nothing I try is working.

Strangely this works just fine for images:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Yet this does **not** always make videos visible in the gallery app:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, vidFile.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

I assure you it is a valid video file, and sometimes the above code works.  I cannot find a pattern for when it will work and when not, though. 
I have also tried a few other variations to getContentResolver().insert.  In fact, If I tell it my video file is an image, it  **always** updates the gallery with a nonviewable image that is my video.
Thanks much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this has been an ordeal, but I found a work-around.  Actually this new solution might be better then what I was trying to do. Depends on the overheads of the various methods I suppose.

As stated by Pascal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114168/android-mediastore-insertvideo), I can update the content provider by broadcasting the proper intent:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAddedOrDeleted)));
```

This makes my videos visible to my gallery app every time (thank god, I was about to resort to writing my own built in viewer)
But I'm still curious why my method works for images but not video, in case anyone knows.