# Launch gallery with Images and Videos get back the selected image/video - Android

Tags: android, video, gallery

I know how to launch default gallery with Images and get back the selected image URI.

Now I am looking for how to launch default gallery with Images and Video displaying together and get back the selected image/video uri back to my application.

Is this possible with default gallery app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check out this post [Android Gallery (view) video (also thumbnail issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925502/android-gallery-view-video-also-thumbnail-issues)

i have used the gallery but only with images.  i would imagine though they are all just drawables (meaning putting a video in the array might work) but i really dont know without testing.
the only other thing is how many videos?  if there are to many your apk will be huge.

the way i did videos in my app was to separate them out and use intents
but you could also keep track of where you are in the gallery and when u hit the spot where the vids should be fire the intent then after the vid is watched come back to the gallery.